# Convert POST array back to POST string data

Tags: php, arrays, post

When you do the following in an HTML form:

```
<input name="one[]" value="foo" />
<input name="one[]" value="bar" />
<input name="two[key]" value="something" />
```

and submit the form to a PHP page, The $_POST array will look as follows:

```
array(
    'one' => array(
        0 => 'foo',
        1 => 'bar'
    ),
    'two' => array(
        'key' => 'something'
    ),
),
```

If you look at the header data, though, it will look as follows:

```
one[]=foo&one[]=bar&two[key]=something
```

Does anyone have a script with which to convert the PHP array back into the POST data string? [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) doesn't work as it can't acces arrays...

---

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want `http_build_query()`

Comment: Why didn't I think of that!? Thanx... :)